# Java template system with IDE support

Tags: java, eclipse, template-engine, freemarker

I am currently using [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) in my application, with a complex model to generate [Drools](http://drools.jboss.org/) rules (just to tell, not important here).

Those template are more and more complex, and I find it hard to maintain the model on one side, populate the data for freemarker, and then maintain the template separately without IDE support, or even compile-time **warning /errors**.

I would like to be able to write something like a **JSP page**, but not in the context of a J2EE application, nor for output rendering : Just for internal of my application.

I would like to be able to declare my variable and their types at top of the file, and have compile time errors if my template is incorrect.

I am aware of the [Universal Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html), but could not find an implementation with good IDE (Eclipse) support.

I would like something like:

```
# world:World

Print Hello ${world.name}
```

And

```
public class World {
  String getName();
}
```

If I write `${world.names}`, I would like my IDE/compiler to complain.

Do you have any idea of such tool/library ?

Comment: It doesn't solve what you ask for (or not completely), but I hope you are using at least the JBoss FreeMarker plugin.